# A sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ which converge pointwise a.e. but does not converge uniformly on any interval

Tags: real-analysis

How to construct a sequence of functions that are defined and continuous on $[0,1]$ and it converges to zero a.e. but on any interval it does not converge uniformly?

Comment: what about $x^n$ ?

Comment: See example 7.4, page 77,  in [*Counterexamples in Analysis*](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_analysis.html?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC), Gelbaum and Olmsted. There, a sequence of continuous functions is constructed that converge to the function $f(x)=\cases{1/q,&$x=p/q$ in lowest terms, $p$ and $q$ integers, $q>0$\cr 0,&$x$ irrational}$

Comment: $x^n\to 0$ uniformly on $[0,a]$ for $a<1$

Comment: @David: with a couple more lines that could easily been an answer.

Comment: @DavidMitra:I've found it, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See example 7.4, page 77, in [Counterexamples in Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_analysis.html?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC), Gelbaum and Olmsted (the nice diagram on page 79 gives the essential idea of the construction).

There, a sequence of continuous functions is constructed that converges to the function $f(x)=\cases{1/q,&$x=p/q$ in lowest terms, $p$ and $q$ integers with $q>0$\cr 0,&$x$ irrational}$.

That  the convergence is not uniform on any interval follows from the fact that $f$ is discontinuous at every rational $x$, and the fact that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.