# Give an example of a sequence of continuous functions which converges on a compact set to a function that has an infinite number of discontinuities.

Tags: analysis

Give an example of a sequence of continuous functions which converges on a compact set to a function that has an infinite number of discontinuities.

Analysis is something that is very difficult for me, and I am not fully sure what I am supposed to give an example of, but this is my attempt (hopefully some of it is right):

Let C be the Cantor Set (since it is compact and has an infinite number of discontinuities).

Let C1, C2,... be subsets of C and the union of all Cn's = C.

Let F = (fn) where for all n, fn: [0,1] -> Cn

Let fn = |x|

Then the midpoints of all Cn will converge to 0 and the endpoints of each Cn will converge to 1.

Any help or corrections is greatly appreciated!

Comment: On $[0,1]$, try making the discontinuity set $\{1/n|n\in \Bbb N\}$. Define $f_n$ to be continuous and piecewise linear with value $1$ at each $x=1/n$ and $0$ "most everywhere else". Do so in such a way that the limit function is $g(x)=0$ if $x\ne 1/n$, $g(1/n)=1$. (I think this is what you're trying to do, but you don't have to be fancy about it.)

Comment: More complicated constructions can be made. The discontinuity set can even be dense. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405571/a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-on-0-1-which-converge-pointwise-a-e-but).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a variation of the hint given by David Mitra. Let $C\subset [0,1]$ be a closed set with empty interior (could be the Cantor set, if you wish). Recall   the definition of distance function $$d(x,C)=\inf_{y\in C}|x-y|$$ 
The triangle inequality implies $|d(x_1,C)-d(x_2,C)|\le |x_1-x_2|$. In particular, $d$ is continuous. Define
$$f_n(x) = \max(0,1-n\,d(x,C))$$
which is a continuous function, being built from $d$ in a way that preserves continuity. If $x\in C$, then $f_n(x)=1$ for all $n$. If $x\notin C$, then $d(x,C)>0$ and consequently $f_n(x)=0$ for all large enough $n$.

Conclusion: the limit of $f_n$ is the characteristic function of $C$. The latter is discontinuous at every point of $C$.

Bonus features:  you can get an uncountable set of discontinuities in this way; moreover, if $C$ is a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), the limit function is not even Riemann integrable (because the set of discontinuities has positive measure).

Comment: I was really having a hard time thinking of a way to define the function to make it do what I wanted. This was a great definition! Thank you very much!