# Pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is discontinuous at most finitely/countably many points.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of functions in $C[0,1]$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ pointwise. Then $f$ has at most finitely (or probably countably) many discontinuities. Is this statement TRUE or FALSE? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Nameless You need uniform convergence for that

Comment: @Nameless No, the result is true only if the convergence is UNIFORM. For example, consider $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Egorov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov's_theorem), pointwise convergence almost everywhere implies uniform convergence on a set of measure arbitrarily close to $1$. Therefore $f$ is continuous except possibly on a set of measure $0$.

Edit: Disregard this, it's wrong. I apologize. See Aram's link below in comments, it answers the question. The link is [[Give an example of a sequence of continuous functions which converges on a compact set to a function that has an infinite number of discontinuities.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661221/give-an-example-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-which-converges-on-a-compa)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661221/give-an-example-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-which-converges-on-a-compa), from which we can see both that the above is wrong (by choosing C to be a nowhere dense set of positive measure, having the sequence converge to the characteristic function of C) and that the answer to your question is false, by noting that a set of positive measure is uncountable.

Comment: Thanks. But measure zero sets may not be countable, for example the Cantor set. If this happens then my statement is FALSE. Could give a counterexample then?

Comment: Egorov's theorem does not describe the "geometry" of the "small set" where uniform convergence does not happen, so it may be something very irregular (e.g. a dense susbset) which totally scrambles the continuity.

Comment: Wait, by the Baire-Osgood theorem the set of discontinuitys is a set of the first category, and sets of first category can have measure greater than zero.... in fact look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661221/give-an-example-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-which-converges-on-a-compa

Comment: You do have that the restriction of $f$ to $X \setminus N$ is continuous. But this says nothing about $f$ on $X$ as a whole. That is, if $f$ is continuous on $X$ then it is continuous on any subspace, but $f$ being continuous on a subspace of $X$ does not imply that it is continuous on the whole space. This is still true even if the subspace in question is dense, perhaps surprisingly.

Comment: @Aram Thanks for the link. It answers my question.