# A function that converges pointwise but not uniformly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Give an example of a sequence of functions $f_n \in C(X)$ (where $X$ is a compact metric space), and a function $f \in C(X)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise, but not uniformly.

I am having trouble with the condition that $f_n$ and $f$ are in $C(X)$, so I assume they both need to be continuous?

Comment: [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) shows $f_n$ can't be monotone in that case. Hope this helps.

Comment: On $[0,1]$, let the graph of $f_n$ be the line segments connecting $(0,0)$ to $(1/n,1)$, $(1/n,1)$ to $(2/n,0)$, and $(2/n,0)$ to $(1,0)$ ($n>2$).

Comment: I simply cannot believe there aren't alread several examples of this in the site. Have  you looked?

Comment: [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405571/a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-on-0-1-which-converge-pointwise-a-e-but) a somewhat extreme example.

Comment: @cronos2 that does help, thank you! So I assume that can apply to the moving hats example that David Mitra described which does in fact converge point wise to 0 but not uniformly

Comment: There is a counterexample in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588976/to-prove-that-f-nx-fracnx1n2x2-does-not-uniformly-converge-to-fx)

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1],$ and if $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in\{0\}\cup[\frac1n,1],$ then we know enough to conclude that $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Can you somehow contrive to complete the definition of $f_n$ so that the sequence does not converge uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_n$ = $\frac{nx}{1+n^2 x^2}$ where $x$ $\epsilon$ $[0,1]$.Here the limit function for the above sequence is $f$ = $0$ when for all $x$ $\epsilon$ $[0,1]$.

Clearly, $f_n$ = $\frac{nx}{1+n^2 x^2}$ is a sequence of continuous functions and $f$ is also continuous.

Now, $M_n$ $=$ $sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ = $sup_{x \in [0,1]} \frac{nx}{1+n^2 x^2}$ $=$ $\frac{1}{2}$.

So by $M_n$ test, $f_n$ converges to f pointwise, not uniformly.

Comment: $f$ was supposed to be continuous

Comment: I hope this example works.