# Sequence of functions converges

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, problem-solving, pointwise-convergence

I'm searching for sequence of functions that converge pointwise on $\mathbb{R}$ but not uniformly on any interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, there is a bijection $f:\Bbb Q \to \Bbb N$.

Define a sequence of functions $$
g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0,&x\notin\Bbb Q,\\
1, & x\in\Bbb Q,\quad f(x)\ge n,\\
0, & x\in\Bbb Q,\quad f(x)< n
\end{cases}
$$

The sequence $\{g_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $0$ pointwisely on $\Bbb  R$, but not uniformly on any interval.

Comment: Can you explain more about the converge

Comment: There is no specific formula for f (x)??

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to define a sequence of continuous functions with this property. One example is as follows.

We aim to get a sequence of functions which converge to the function given by 
$f(p/q)=1/q$ if $p/q$ is in lowest terms with $q>0$, $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.

To do this, let $f_n$ be the function defined by $f(p/q)=1/q$ if $p/q$ in lowest terms with $0<q\leq n$, and $f_n$ is piecewise linear between these points. Each $f_n$ is continuous, and certainly $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(p/q)=1/q$ for each $p,q$ coprime.

Now we just need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational. Suppose not, so there is some $x$ irrational with $f_n(x)>\delta>0$ infinitely often. Now let $m=\lfloor 1/\delta\rfloor$, and suppose the nearest rational with denominator at most $m$ to $x$ is at distance $\epsilon$ from $x$. Now for any $n>1/\epsilon$ we have rationals with denominator $n$ which are closer to $x$ (on both sides) than $\epsilon$. Thus the closest rationals on both sides with denominator $\leq n$ are closer than any rational of denominator $\leq m$; it follows by piecewise linearity that $f_n(x)<1/m<\delta$, contradiction.

Comment: That's really neat!

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to my original suspicion, a satisfactory sequence of continuous functions exists; see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405571/a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-on-0-1-which-converge-pointwise-a-e-but/405594#405594) from the comment below

One example of a sequence of discontinuous functions is as follows: define
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  q &\text{if }x=\tfrac{p}{q}\quad (x \text{ is rational), with }p \in \mathbb Z \text{ and } q \in \mathbb N \text{ coprime}\\
  0           &\text{if }x\text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$
and take the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{f(x)}{n}$.  The important fact about $f$ here is that it is unbounded on every interval.

Comment: And how I can prove that this sequence  coverage pointwise? ?

Comment: @HelenAlshelli at any $x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x)/n = 0$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy as I said, that's what I think. If you can point to an example that shows otherwise I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: @KaboMurphy I think the question whether we can build such an example with continuous functions (or prove that for continuous functions we can not find it) is worth another post.

Comment: @HelenAlshelli I don't understand your question

Comment: I'm asking how you prove that this sequence don't converge uniformly

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405571/a-sequence-of-continuous-functions-on-0-1-which-converge-pointwise-a-e-but/405594#405594) is an example with continuous functions.

Comment: I'm wondering if we can draw a function with this characters then we can find the formula of this function ? But I don't have mathematica  right now

Comment: @HelenAlshelli show that over any interval: for any $n$ and for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $x$ in that interval such that $f_n(x) > \epsilon$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I want continues function on all R not interval [0,1]

Comment: @HelenAlshelli this function is not continuous on any interval, so I don't think that it can be "drawn" in a useful way

Comment: There's no way ever to find continues one ? I think this is the point of the question! That's tricky somehow :/

Comment: @HelenAlshelli It is possible, as others have said in the comments and as the latest answer indicates. That being said, I don't think that there's an example that is easy to visualize, which based on your comments seems to be what you are really looking for.

Comment: @HelenAlshelli also, note that David's example can be extended to $\Bbb R$